# Разница между двума датами в секундах в Django

Tags: python, django, дата

Хочу получить разницу (в секундах) между двумя датами: текущей и даты, взятой из базы:

models.py:

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    dateAdded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

в консоле:

```
from phone_book.models import Tasks   
this = Tasks.objects.get(id = 50).dateAdded.replace(tzinfo = None)    
import datetime   
now = datetime.datetime.now()    # судя инструкции разница между now и this должна дать мне необходимую разницу  
delta = now - time
```

В результате объект `delta` возвращает `datetime.timedelta(1, 4451, 467165)`,
у которого есть аргумент `seconds`, но почему-то в результате `delta.seconds` выводится значение `4451`, которое значительно отличается от фактической разницы между двумя датами.

В общем вопрос: как мне найти разницу между двумя датами в секундах, либо подскажите ссылочку на умный источник.

Спасибо!

Comment: извините, что не отредактировал вывод models.py  в вопросе, заметил, когда уже отправил

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Разница в секундах между временем на сегодня и заданной датой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/722338/23044)

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> a
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 7, 14, 34, 14, 63000)
>>> b = datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 7, 14, 50, 00)
>>> b
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 7, 14, 50)
>>> c = b - a
>>> c
datetime.timedelta(0, 945, 937000)
>>> c.seconds
945
>>> c.seconds / 60
15
```

вроде верно все

Comment: действительно, пока набирал твой код, в голову пришла мысль, что у меня время на сервере может сильно отличаться от времени на компе, оттого и такая разница, буду копать в этом направлении, спасибо за косвенную помощь

Comment: а как найти список тайм зон?

Comment: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#helpers

ну и вообще http://djbook.ru/rel1.4/topics/i18n/timezones.html

Comment: datetime.now() возвращает наивный datetime объект -- не используйте его. См. [Как к нынешней дате добавить 30 минут?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/659229/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [`USE_TZ=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/), чтобы django использовала бы время, включающее информацию о часовой зоне. Иначе, вычитая наивные datetime объекты, вы можете ошибку на тысячи секунд получить (к примеру, в районе перехода на летнее время).

Чтобы получить текущее время:

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
```

`datetime.now()` возвращает наивный datetime объект -- не используйте его.

Имея datetime с установленным правильным `tzinfo`, можно уже напрямую вычитать: `now - then`.