# Как к нынешней дате добавить 30 минут?

Tags: python, datetime

Нужно взять дату и время, и добавить к времени 30 минут.
Как вывести дату и время знаю, но вот никак не получаеться добавить 30 минут:

```
import time
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.now()
print dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

# -> 27.04.2017 13:07
```

Кто подскажет?

Comment: cвязанный вопрос: [How can I subtract a day from a Python date?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/441147/4279)

Answer (score 15):

Чтобы получить `datetime` значение, соответствующее половине оборота минутной стрелки (30 минут по часам) от текущего значения:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

clock_in_half_hour = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=30)
```

Если вы хотите получить локальное время, которое будет через 1800 секунд от текущего в будущее, то это значение может отличаться из-за перевода часов (к примеру, из-за разницы между летним/зимним временем в текущей часовой зоне). В этом случае следует использовать datetime с tzinfo (Питон 3):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

future_in_half_hour = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(minutes=30)
local_time = future_in_half_hour.astimezone()
```

python на текущей платформе может не иметь доступа к [tz database](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) (Windows) или на старых Питон версиях нет timezone модуля. Самый переносимый вариант это использовать информацию о часовых поясах из [`pytz` модуля](http://pythonhosted.org/pytz/):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz     # $ pip install pytz
import tzlocal  # $ pip install tzlocal

local_timezone = tzlocal.get_localzone()  # pytz-timezone

future_in_half_hour = datetime.now(pytz.utc) + timedelta(minutes=30)
local_time = future_in_half_hour.astimezone(local_timezone)
```

`tzlocal` модуль используется, чтобы найти `pytz` временну́ю зону, соответствующую локальной часовой зоне.

[`pendulum`](https://pendulum.eustace.io/) позволяет скрыть эти детали, связанные со сменой смещения от UTC в местном времени:

```
import pendulum  # $ pip install pendulum

future_in_half_hour = pendulum.now().add(minutes=30)
```

Дополнительная информация:

- [Как получить часовой пояс на Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/135134/23044)
- [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279)

Если вы не знали, что местное время может повторяться (не монотонно, не уникально) или вообще отсутствовать, посмотрите на картинки в [python converting string in localtime to UTC epoch timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32723834/4279).

Answer (score 6):

Используйте `timedelta`.

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

now = datetime.now()
after_30_minutes = now + timedelta(minutes=30)
```

Comment: @АндрейПетров: это может вернуть неверный результат, если вам нужно местное время +1800 секунд в будущее. Обратите внимание, что в часовых зонах, использующих зимнее/летнее время (или в которых местное смещение от UTC может поменяться по любой другой (e.g., политической) причине) не следует проводить арифметику с "наивными" datetime объектами без корректной tzinfo. Если не хотите думать о подобных деталях, то [можно использовать pendulum](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/659256/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Прибавте разницу во времени с учетом часового пояса, как то так:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> now = dt.datetime.now(dt.timezone.utc)
>>> print(now.astimezone())
2020-02-05 20:26:20.183996+03:00
>>> now = now + dt.timedelta(minutes=30)
>>> print(now.astimezone())
2020-02-05 20:56:20.183996+03:00
```