# Сравнение даты-времени парсера из xpath с реальной датой-временем

Tags: python-3.x, requests, datetime

Есть дата и время, динамические, обновляются на сайте постоянно.
Я их парсером получаю через xpath.

Как теперь это полученное значение сравнить с текущей датой и временем, и если текущее время больше значения на 5 мин, к примеру, то выполняет, например, принт?

В общем суть задачи, парсер оборудования, которое постоянно мониторится и выводится на html в виде времени и даты:

```
import requests
import datetime
from lxml import html

response = requests.get(URL)
parsed_body = html.fromstring(response.text)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
now1 = now.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

a = 'hostname'
b = str(parsed_body.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[001]/td[1]/text()'))
c = str(parsed_body.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[001]/td[2]/text()'))

print(a + b + c)
```

Comment: Привели бы в какую переменную вытаскиваете время и какое в ней значение

Comment: в чём у вас сложности? Ясно ли как строку в datetime превратить? ясно как datetime сравнивать и как 5 минут прибавить? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/659229/23044

Comment: Вытаскиваю как уже говори через xpath время, оно выводится вот в таком виде: ['25.10.2017 10:29:28'] именно так, с ковычками и скобками. Т.е если смотреть код получится по сути: с = ['25.10.2017 10:29:28']