# Вывод даты и времени python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как форматировать дату и время для вывода в консоль.
Мне нужно вывести дату и время которое сейчас и -1 день от этого времени

```
date = datetime.datetime.today()
print('now ', date)
```

Но выводит 2017-12-07 19:52:32.297026
Как убрать миллисекунды и вывести время которое было 24ч назад
Нашел, что можно как то так

```
date, date.day - 1
```

но этот способ не сработал

Comment: strftime попробуйте, а еще лучше почитайте документацию на модуль datetime, там много интересного и полезного.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Спасибо, помогло

Comment: Чтение документации помогает, да...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Да нет, strftime. Но все же в доках или просто в гугле не могу найти толком как поставить день назад

Comment: timedelta тоже в доках есть :)

Comment: @andreymal если я отнимаю вот так date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S')
newdate = date - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
то выдает ошибку
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Comment: Ну да, отнимать надо от даты, а не от строки

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как к нынешней дате добавить 30 минут?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/659229/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй так..

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.today()
print('now ', date)
print('day ago ', date - datetime.timedelta(1))

# форматируем вывод
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior
print('now ', date.strftime("%A %d %B %Y"))
```

Comment: Да, первый способ работает, но у меня строка в формате date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S')
И от нее не хочет минусовать ничего ибо этот строка вроде.
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Comment: Можно конечно .strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S') не добавлять в переменную, а в вывод добавить, но тогда в таймдельте уже будут миллисекунды и .strftime к нему не применить

Answer (score 3):

> Как убрать миллисекунды

Чтобы получить строку без миллисекунд, просто не указывайте их в желаемом выходном формате:

```
>>> import datetime as DT
>>> now = DT.datetime.now(DT.timezone.utc).astimezone()
>>> time_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
>>> f"{now:{time_format}}"
'2018-04-11 16:21:50'
```

Вариант с `str(now.replace(microsecond=0, tzinfo=None))` [гарантированно](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.isoformat) тот же результат здесь даёт. [DateTime in ISO 8601 + TimeZone and without microseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28195256/4279). Если вам только напечатать без микросекунд нужно, то предпочтительней явно формат задать, не меняя значение самого времени.

> Как ... вывести время которое было 24ч назад

```
>>> h24ago = (now.astimezone(DT.timezone.utc) - DT.timedelta(hours=24)).astimezone()
>>> f"{h24ago:{time_format}}"
'2018-04-10 16:21:50'
```

`astimezone()` вызовы нужны, чтобы работало в районе переходов с зимнего на летнее время (и подобное). Подробнее: [Как к нынешней дате добавить 30 минут?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/659229/23044)

Answer (score 1):

```
date = datetime.datetime.today()
newdata = date - datetime.timedelta(1)
print(newdata.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S')
```