# Python - datetime. Как в отображении timedelta убрать миллисекунды

Tags: python, дата, datetime, время, timedelta

Пишу игру. И немного запутался в формулах подсчёта времени с использованием datetime и timedelta.
А точнее с выводом на экран. Скрипт все хорошо считает, с учетом бонуса от дополнительного навыка. Но, хочу убрать отображение миллисекунд.

```
working_hours = int(input 'Введите кол-во часов')

char_characteristic['working_end'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(datetime.now().timestamp()) + (timedelta(minutes=working_hours * 60) - ((timedelta(minutes=working_hours * 60) / 100) * char_characteristic['speed_skill']))

work_end_time = char_characteristic["working_end"] - datetime.fromtimestamp(datetime.now().timestamp())

print(work_ent_time)
```

Отображается в виде: 0:25:29.358868.

Хочу сделать, чтобы отображалось 0:25:29.

Пробовал разные варианты: strptime, strftime, просто, через str().

Подскажите, пожалуйста как поправить код, а то уже несколько дней пытаюсь с этим разобраться, и не получается.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755275/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-python3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У класса `timedelta()` действительно нет встроенных удобных методов для того, чтобы убрать миллисекунды, но есть простое решение, которое я нашел на [англоязычной версии вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29669412/19736488):

Так как вам это нужно только для печати - можно воспользоваться тем, что у `timedelta` формат всегда одинаков и не выводить последнюю часть, предварительно отделив ее.

```
HH:MM:SS.FFF
        ^^^^
```

Код выглядит так:

```
from datetime import timedelta

delta = timedelta(days=1, hours=3, minutes=42, seconds=54, microseconds=24)

print(delta)
print(str(delta).split('.')[0])
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 1 day, 3:42:54.000024
> 1 day, 3:42:54
> ```