# AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'

Tags: python, python-3.x, время, datetime

```
self.start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
uptime = (datetime.datetime.now() - self.start_time.total_seconds())

hours, remainder = divmod(uptime, 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
await self.api.status.set(text=f" Аптайм: {'%02d:%02d:%02d' % (hours, minutes, seconds)}")
```

Почему `total_seconds()`не находит?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как к нынешней дате добавить 30 минут?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/659229/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вопросе опечатка, правильно так:

```
uptime = (datetime.datetime.now() - self.start_time).total_seconds()
```

---

Дело в том, что `total_seconds()` метод `timedelta`, а не `datetime`. Если сделать вычитание объектов `datetime`, то будет возвращен объект `timedelta`:

```
import datetime as DT

start_time = DT.datetime.now()
print(type(start_time))  # <class 'datetime.datetime'>

uptime = (DT.datetime.now() - start_time)
print(type(uptime))  # <class 'datetime.timedelta'>
print(uptime.total_seconds())  # 0.0
```

Comment: Понял, благодарю за решение проблемы

Comment: @Михаил если местное время может быть летним/зимним или по любой другой причине смещение от UTC поменяется, то `datetime.now()-whatever` может вернуть ошибочный результат. Используйте datetime с явным часовым поясом, к примеру, `datetime.now(timezone.utc)` (у обоих параметров должен часовой пояс быть установлен).

Comment: Нет. Это просто вычитание времени с момента включения, UTC не имеет значения