# Как прибавить к времени какое-то кол-во

Tags: python, datetime

Получаю время через:

```
datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Как прибавить к времени в таком виде, к примеру 2 часа?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как к нынешней дате добавить 30 минут?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/659229/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-30-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае вы получаете не просто время, а уже преобразованное время в строку определенного формата - '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' - его можно редактировать:

```
a = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
print(a)
print(type(a))
>>> 23/01/2020 12:18:57
>>> <class 'str'>
```

Чтобы получить значение, с которым можно будет производиться вычисления, достаточно оставить:

```
a = datetime.datetime.today()
print(a)
print(type(a))
>>> 2020-01-23 12:18:20.123781
>>> <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Для получения значения времени для последующих вычислений, удобно пользоваться

```
datetime.timedelta()
```

В скобках указать необходимое значение

```
days: float = ..., seconds: float = ..., microseconds: float = ...,
milliseconds: float = ..., minutes: float = ..., hours: float = ...,
weeks: float = ..., *, fold: int = ...
```

Например два часа:

```
datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
```

Таким образом работа со временем будет выглядить так:

```
 a = datetime.datetime.today()
 b = datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
 c = a + b
 d = a - b
 print(c)
 print(d)

>>>2020-01-23 14:24:08.090274
>>>2020-01-23 10:24:08.090274
```

А далее форматировать результат в тот формат, который вам нужен для выдачи `strftime(НУЖНЫЙ_ФОРМАТ)`

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
import datetime as DT

date = DT.datetime.today()
print(date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
# 23/01/2020 15:19:55

date += DT.timedelta(hours=2)
print(date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
# 23/01/2020 17:19:55
```