# Список из времени от 03:00 до 00:00 c шагом 5 минут

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как, используя Python, можно сформировать список из значений времени с шагом в 5 минут. На выходе должно получиться следующее:

mylist=[03:00,03:05,03:10 ...]

Comment: Показанный вами пример списка синтаксически некорректен. Какой реальный тип данных должен получиться в результате?

Comment: Попробуй вот это почитать, мб пойдет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/659229/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-30-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82 а дальше как то вот так перекидываешь каждое время в строку https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-datetime.html ну, и ставишь цикл `while новое расчетное время != ну ты же знаешь сколько в 00:00 времени?`. И в цикле запихиваешь строчные параметры в список.

Answer (score 2):

если значения времени нужны в строковом виде, то вот простенький цикл:

```
h = 3
m = 0
t = h * 60 + m
mylist = []

while t < 1441:
    mylist += [f'{t//60:02d}:{t%60:02d}']
    t += 5

print(mylist)

#
['03:00', '03:05', '03:10', '03:15',..., '23:50', '23:55', '24:00']
```

а если нужен тип времени, то можно попробовать так:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time

t = datetime(2021,8,25,3,0,0)
mylist = [t.time()]

while t.time() != time(0,0,0):
    t += timedelta(minutes=5)
    mylist += [t.time()]
    
print(mylist)

#
[datetime.time(3, 0), datetime.time(3, 5), datetime.time(3, 10),
...
...
 datetime.time(23, 50), datetime.time(23, 55), datetime.time(0, 0)]
```

Comment: Я бы это `mylist += [t.time()]` лучше заменил на `mylist.append(t.time())` :)