# Разница в секундах между временем на сегодня и заданной датой

Tags: python

Как на python посчитать разницу в секундах между временем на сегодня и датой рождения, которую пользователь вводит сам?

Comment: В каком месте возникли трудности? Покажите код.

Comment: Подсказка: используйте модуль [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Comment: Напишите хотя бы в каком формате будут передаваемые данные, дату рождения же можно предать по разному.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как к нынешней дате добавить 30 минут?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/659229/23044)

Answer (score 3):

Допустим вы родились в New York, тогда время рождения записывается с точностью до минуты. Так как вы сейчас можете быть в другом часовом поясе, то следует явно указать часовую зону:

```
>>> import pendulum   # $ pip install pendulum
>>> birthtime = pendulum.create(1999, 9, 11, 23, 10, tz='America/New_York')
>>> age = pendulum.now() - birthtime
>>> age.in_seconds()
569173149
```

Comment: А если родился в Васюках, тогда время рождения не записывается с точностью до минуты? ;-)

Comment: @Kromster: на свидетельствах о рождении я только день вижу.

Comment: Зачем минус ответу ставить? Отзовись подлый трус ;)

Comment: Так и в вопросе только дата фигурирует. В целом не очень понятен реверанс в сторону часов/поясов/минут. *не минусовал*

Comment: @Kromster: ответ на вопрос "как посчитать разницу в секундах" обязан принимать во внимание часовые пояса. Если не ясно, то подробнее можно почитать по [ссылке, я выше привёл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/659256/23044)

Comment: Не обязан. По крайней мере в ТЗ даны только две точки - дата и датавремя на сегодня. Никаких уточнений и данных про ЧП (а также летнее/зимнее, реформы и т.п.) не дано. В данном случае, я бы расположил все "special case", "учтите" и "а также" ниже ответа.

Comment: @Kromster вы не одиноки в подобных взглядах (что точный результат это "специальный случай", а не норма) поэтому и нельзя доверять большинству программ при работе со временем. Может быть хуже: я слышал от человека, который поддерживает достаточно популярную библиотеку по работе с датами: в ответ на моё замечание про зимнее/летнее время, он сказал типа "ну и что всего лишь час в году неправильный результат" (на самом деле неправильный результат получался всегда когда даты были по разную сторону от перехода с одного самого пояса на другой) — я подобным библиотекам не доверяю.

Comment: я с вами согласен, и в реальных задачах обработки данных это все имеет большое значение.

Comment: Непонятно - зачем минусовать верный ответ...

Answer (score 0):

Импортируй datetime, в нем есть такая функция как timedelta, которая и высчитывает разницу.

Comment: наивное вычитание без учёта часовой зоны, может избегаемую ошибку внести в вычисления (для дня рождения это может и не важно, но в общем случае желательно не вносить ~часовые ошибки при вычитании времени).